# Django self-referential foreign key

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I'm kind of new to webapps and database stuff in general so this might be a dumb question. I want to make a model ("CategoryModel") with a field that points to the primary id of another instance of the model (its parent).

```
class CategoryModel(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(CategoryModel)
```

How do I do this? Thanks!

Comment: Stylistically, I would suggest calling this `parent` instead of `parentId`, since `my_category_model.parent` will be an instance of `CategoryModel`. Django will automatically create a member `parent_id` which will be the primary key of the related model.

Answer (score 370, accepted):

You can pass in the name of a model as a string to ForeignKey and it will do the right thing.

So:

```
parent = models.ForeignKey("CategoryModel")
```

Or you can use the string "self"

```
parent = models.ForeignKey("self")
```

Comment: how to handle the root instance if not setting null=True / blank = True ?

Comment: @zypro you can't. You HAVE to make it nullable.

Comment: `parent = models.ForeignKey("self")` more readable

Answer (score 80):

You can use the string 'self' to indicate  a self-reference.

```
class CategoryModel(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self')
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey

Comment: I think you mean 'self'. As in the string. self is undefined in this context

Comment: @Brandon How is 'self' in your answer different from what jared has said in his comment? "i think you mean 'self" !!! . Both are string which is fine according to django docs. ! Any hints

Comment: The difference is that `self` isn't present when defining the model property. If the property were being defined as part of the `__init__()` or another method, it would be, as `self` is always the first positional argument to any instance method of a Python class.

Answer (score 22):

You also to set `null=True` and `blank=True`

```
class CategoryModel(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey("self", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

`null=True`, to allow in database
`blank=True`, to allow in form validation

Answer (score 8):

https://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-orm-cookbook/en/latest/self_fk.html

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    manager = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

OR

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    manager = models.ForeignKey("app.Employee", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

https://stackabuse.com/recursive-model-relationships-in-django/