# Django self-referential foreign key with related_name doesn't work

Tags: django, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I followed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15285626/django-self-referential-foreign-key) to create a model pointing to itself with a ForeignKey. I just added the related_name option. The model looks like this:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    best_friend = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, 
                                    related_name='considered_best_friend_for')

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name
```

Then I did the following:

```
>>> a = Person.objects.create(name='Albert')
>>> a.save()
>>> j = Person.objects.create(name='John')
>>> j.save()
>>> m = Person.objects.create(name='Mark')
>>> m.save()
>>> a.best_friend = m
>>> a.save()
>>> j.best_friend = m
>>> j.save()
>>> m.considered_best_friend_for.all()
[]
>>> m.considered_best_friend_for
<django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager object at 0x102503190>
```

I don't understand why when I query `m.considered_best_friend_for.all()` I get an empty result `[]`. I was expecting to get `[<Albert>, <John>]`. However, if I query `m.considered_best_friend_for` I get the RelateManager object.
Where is the mistake?

*Note: I tried the same code changing the ForeignKey for a ManyToMany relationship and it worked, but in this case I need a ForeignKey relationship because a person can be considered best friend for more than one person (or zero), but can only consider one (or zero) person his/her best friend.*

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Mistake found!** I was using a custom manager (needed for another part of the code) that was filtering out the results. Sorry about that! :)