# How can I combine fields in a Django Queryset?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-filter

I am new to Django and I am trying to figure out how to create a Model Multiple Choice Filter. I am currently trying to create a filter that will filter pets by type, for example cat, dog, bird,  etc. The problem I'm running into is that there are a bunch of breeds (ex: husky in dogs), so when I do a queryset that orders by animal type I get way more options than I want. Is there a way to make it so the filter will only display the animal type, but when clicked, will actually query for all the breeds within that type?

Comment: can you add your pets model with the fields involved in the question?

Comment: please show us some code of what you have tried

Comment: This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48262544/how-to-specify-parent-child-relationship-within-one-model) might help you out. Good look!