# Is it possible to create foreignkey with it's self?

Tags: django, django-models

I have this model,

```
class Perfume_User(models.Model):
    Sponsor_User = models.ForeignKey('Perfume_User', on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: please elaborate what exactly you want to do.

Comment: Django model that has a foreign key reference by itself? just like in my models in my question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django self-referential foreign key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15285626/django-self-referential-foreign-key)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it is possible , you can do :

```
class Perfume_User(models.Model):
    Sponsor_User = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True, null=True)
```

you can read more here : [Django Foreign keys](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey)

Comment: when i try to create user in the admin, i receive this error """"django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: zoom_user.time_referral_id""""